# Вопросы форматирования кода

Tags: java, форматирование

Решил поинтересоваться у сообщества, какие приемы оформления кода вы используете.
Кое-где подсмотрел такой прием и до сих пор не знаю, корректно ли им пользоваться.

Вар. 1

```
            Integer resourceId          = items.get(position);
            Integer resourceId_number   = productNumber.get(position);
            Integer resourceId_name     = productName.get(position);
            Integer resourceId_logo     = productLogo.get(position);
            String resourceId_valid     = validThru.get(position);

            tvCardLastDigits    .setText(resourceId_number);
            ivCardLogoMini      .setImageResource(resourceId_logo);
            tvProductType       .setText(resourceId_name);
            tvValidThru         .setText(resourceId_valid);
```

Вар. 2

```
        Integer resourceId = items.get(position);
        Integer resourceId_number = productNumber.get(position);
        Integer resourceId_name = productName.get(position);
        Integer resourceId_logo = productLogo.get(position);
        String resourceId_valid = validThru.get(position);

        tvCardLastDigits.setText(resourceId_number);
        ivCardLogoMini.setImageResource(resourceId_logo);
        tvProductType.setText(resourceId_name);
        tvValidThru.setText(resourceId_valid);
```

Comment: Тогда уж и методы, и параметры отбивать.

Мне лично не очень читабельно, но кому-то нравится.

Comment: т.е. вар2 предпочтительнее?

Comment: советую почитать книгу Чистый код

Comment: intellij IDEA ctrl+alt+L

Comment: Может, примеры своего кода кинете?

Comment: Вар.1 - редко встречающийся стиль. Так кодят в основном асмеры старой закалки или их падаваны =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное правило - это понятность и читабельность исходного текста. При этом не стоит отбрасывать такую важную вещь, как привычки. В данном случае это не очень читабельно, так как вертикальное выравнивание не дает тут преимуществ. В первых случаях опытный программист хорошо видит знаки равенства, вы только тратите время на движения глазами от одной половины к другой, во второй вы разрываете логически элементы, и опять же видимости большей тут не надо.

Вертикальные выравнивания иногда помогают при перечислениях:

```
Integer resourceId,
        resourceId_number,
        resourceId_name,
        resourceId_logo;
```

Хороши порой в условиях:

```
if( resourceId_number>100 && resourceId_number<100 ||
     resourceId == 100     && resourceId < 20) 
{
}
```

Могут пригодится в функциях, когда много параметров и в строку их не наглядно записывать:

```
void someFunc(setName, setLastName,
              setYear, setBirthday, ...)
{
}
```

В цепочных вызовах могут быть:

```
someObject.getActiveWindowWorkRectangle()
          .getTotalPixelsInWorkArea()
          .convertToRGBPointList();
```

Или в других случаях, когда данные слишком смешиваются и надо показать логику. Но в данных случаях, по моему мнению, такое выравнивание только мешает и отвлекает.

Ну и самое главное, форматирование кода - это только рекомендации))

Comment: в принципе вообще не желательно передавать в методы больше двух параметром :)

Comment: Наши желания и возможности порой не совпадают ;)

Answer (score 2):

У меня нет четкого стиля кодирования. Ну то есть попробую объяснить так:

1. Собственно, когда идет само кодирование, я не сильно слежу за стилем, есть, конечно, некоторые базовые правила (мои личные), как то: избегаю лишних пробелов и табуляций, жестко слежу за правилами выравнивания фигурных скобок. В общем-то все. В основном упор делаю на *naming convention*.
2. После того как код более-менее устоялся (прошел первичный дебаггинг), обычно напускаю на исходники автоформат средствами IDE.
3. А вот формат автоформата зависит от команды/проекта. Обычно у каждого проекта свой собственный стиль форматирования кода.
4. Особенно удобна в плане поддержки автоформата Intellij IDEA, там можно в частности импортировать/экспортировать стиль кодирования - оч. удобно для обмена внутри команды.

Касательно представленных ТС вариантов стиля, то конечно же "Вариант №2"

Вариант №1 - какой-то девичий что ли :)

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1):

Разрыв пробелами (`tvCardLastDigits    .setText(`) иногда, конечно, красиво смотрится. Но ещё чем он плох - просто так уже поиском не найти все вхождения, допустим, вызовов setText всех переменных, оканчивающихся на digits. А частенько нужно искать, так сказать, похожие сущности.

Теоретически, конечно, всё равно можно найти, если IDE поддерживает поиск по регулярным выражениям или умный рефакторинг, но это уже не так просто

Comment: Во всех IDE есть поиск по регулярным выражениям. И даже в не IDE есть.

Answer (score 0):

Выравнивание по столбцам имеет смысл только в некоторых конкретных ситуациях. А именно, выполнение ряда похожих, либо одинаковых действий. Обычно в таких случаях разделяю колонки отступами в 3 пробела.

Примеры не на джаве, но это неважно.

Столбцы:

```
&.users      {   background-position: -16px -256px;   }
&.accounts   {   background-position: -16px -272px;   }
&.posts      {   background-position: -16px -288px;   }
// Ещё куча иконок...
```

По правилам:

```
&.users {
  background-position: -16px -256px;
}

&.accounts {
  background-position: -16px -272px;
}

&.posts {
  background-position: -16px -288px;
}
```

Были и более сложные примеры, но их сложно найти и не слишком хорошо выкладывать.